# Filter over Calculated column over the SharePoint List view does not work

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, list-view, modern-experience, calculated-column

I have a SharePoint list. It has a column called 'Closed Date', it keeps only date value of date only type and optional. Now I have created one more calculated column called Closing Year. The formula for the closing year field is as below:

```
=IF(ISBLANK([Closed Date]),"",TEXT([Closed Date],"YYYY"))
```

Now the calculated field is able to show Year value for respective records if closed date is not blank otherwise empty value.

On the list view page, If I try to explicitly filter with any year value as displayed under the filter popup options, it does not return any result. It displays no result.

Kindly help me with this as I am stuck here.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try use settings like below for your calculated column:

[image]

**List View without filter**:

[image]

**List View with filter**:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for replying over this. The Issue I observed like before it was working with the filtration. Now it was not broken. As per your suggestion, I deleted and recreated the field and now it is working. Thanks

Comment: Great, glad it worked for you.